# How do I escape multiple characters in an sql like string?

Tags: sql, escaping

A single character can be escaped like this:

```
select * from tableName where columnName like 'CU_C' escape '_';
```

I need to escape multiple characters ("% " and "_"):

```
select * from tableName where columnName like 'C%U_C' escape ??;
```

How do I escape multiple characters?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You misunderstood the meaning of `escape`: it lets you define a character such that when you put it in front of another character, that other character is interpreted literally, not as a meta-character. You need only one such escape character: you can use it to escape any meta-character.

In the example below I used `'#'` as my escape character:

```
select * from tableName where columnName like 'C#%U#_C' escape '#'
```

This tries to match `C%U_C` strings where both `'%'` and `'_'` are interpreted literally, not as a sequence of any characters or any single character.

Answer (score 0):

**Escape Characters**

Example for a single character '' :

```
'high\-voltage'
```

Example for a string or multiple characters '{*string*}' :

```
'{high-voltage}'
```

- *' - ' is a non alnum character*

Reference : https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/text.920/a96518/cqspcl.htm